# Angular 4 Advanced Pie Charts: show NaN as the percentage instead of number

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

Currently, I'm using [ngx-charts](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts) and initially, all my values will be Zero. So it's showing NaN (Because 0/0 is undefined). While DuckDuckGoing I even came across this [bug](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/pull/597). I reinstall ngx-charts to the latest version which is 7.0.1 and yet I'm facing the same problem if NaN. Is there any other way around this?

EDIT:
I even found the correct working code and the result also comes properly.
[image]

but in my code, I'm still facing the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide link to plunker?

Comment: In JavaScript 0/0 = undefined, so you better try to set the value to 0 whenever the result is undefined. so for example `value = x/y ? x/y : 0;`